# how to go about designing a 16 bit carry look ahead adder in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm having some complications on designing a 16 bit carry look-ahead adder in verilog. I have the code here:

```
  module fulladder(a, b, c, s, cout);
    input a, b, c;
    output s, cout;

   xor  #0
    g1(w1, a, b),
    g2(s, w1, c);
   and  #0
    g3(w2, c, b),
    g4(w3, c, a),
    g5(w4, a, b);
   or   #0
    g6(cout, w2, w3, w4);
  endmodule
```

I understand on how ports work, but do I use vectors?

p.s. its in structural verilog. Please dont give me the full code. Just need some understanding. thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to have ports wider than 1 bit?

Comment: @Munkymorgy - yes. I already made a 16 bit ripple carry adder, but cannot wrap my mind around designing a 16 bit carry look-ahead adder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our friend [Wikipedia has a bit about Carry Look-Ahead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder). These are typically put together in 4 bit stages. 4 fulladders with additional logic to calculate the carries.

Assuming a fulladder as specified in the question, with the addition of a generate `g` and propagate `p` output, a 4 bit block might look some thing like:

```
module four_bit_carry_lookahead (
  input  [3:0] a,
  input  [3:0] b,
  input        c,    //Carry in
  output [3:0] s,    //Sum
  output       cout  //Carry
);

  wire [3:1] carry; // 3:1 to align numbers with wikipedia article
  wire [3:0] p;
  wire [3:0] g;

  fulladder add0(.a(a[0]), .b(b[0]), .c(c),        .s(s[0]), .cout() .g(g[0]), .p([0]) );
  fulladder add1(.a(a[1]), .b(b[1]), .c(carry[1]), .s(s[1]), .cout() .g(g[1]), .p([1]) );
  fulladder add2(.a(a[2]), .b(b[2]), .c(carry[2]), .s(s[2]), .cout() .g(g[2]), .p([2]) );
  fulladder add3(.a(a[3]), .b(b[3]), .c(carry[3]), .s(s[3]), .cout() .g(g[3]), .p([3]) );

  carry_lookahead(
   .p    (p    ), //input  [3:0] 
   .g    (g    ), //input  [3:0]
   .c    (carry), //output [3:1]
   .cout (cout )  //output
  );

endmodule
```

The addition outputs required are `g = a & b;` `p = a | b;`.

The logic to implement the carry_lookahead is still required, the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder) should tell you what is required. They are C1, C2, C3 and C4 in this code that would be carry[1], carry[2], carry[3] and cout.

To create a 16 bit adder you can use 4 of these 4 bit sections.

Comment: wow, I looked at the wikipedia article and tried to implement the circuit design for my project. This helped me a lot to understand what's going on. Thank you very much